# Left join command is not showing all results

Tags: sql, left-join

I have a table RESTAURANT:

```
Id | Name
------------------
0  | 'McDonalds'
1  | 'Burger King'
2  | 'Starbucks'
3  | 'Pans'
```

And a table ORDER:

```
Id | ResId | Client
--------------------
0  | 1     | 'Peter'
1  | 2     | 'John'
2  | 2     | 'Peter'
```

Where 'ResId' is a foreign key from RESTAURANT.Id.

I want to select the number of order per restaurant:
Expected result:

```
Restaurant      | Number of orders
----------------------------------
'McDonalds'     | 0
'Burguer King'  | 1
'Starbucks'     | 2
'Pans'          | 0
```

Actual result:

```
Restaurant      | Number of orders
----------------------------------
'McDonalds'     | 0
'Burguer King'  | 1
'Starbucks'     | 2
```

Command used:

```
select r.Name, count(o.ResId) 
from RESTAURANT r 
  left join ORDER o on r.Id like o.ResId 
group by o.ResId;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fix the `group by` clause:

```
select r.name, count(*)  as cnt_orders
from restaurants r 
left join orders o on r.id = o.resid 
group by r.id, r.name;
```

That way, the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses are consistent; I also added the restaurant id to the group, so potential restaurants having the same name are not aggregated together. I also changed `like` to `=`: this is more efficient, and does not alter the logic.

You could also phrase this with a subquery, so there is no need for outer aggregation. I would prefer:

```
select r.*,
    (select count(*) from orders o where o.resid = r.id) as cnt_orders
from restaurants r
```

Comment: I would of thought a left join would be more efficient that a correlated sub query.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be generating an error because the `select` columns and the `group by` columns are incompatible.  Just aggregate by the unaggregated columns in the `select`:

```
select r.Name, count(o.ResId)
from RESTAURANT r left join
     ORDER o
     on r.Id = o.ResId
group by r.Name;
```

Notes:

- You might want to include `r.id` in the `GROUP BY` (and `SELECT`) in case restaurants can have the same name.
- Note the use of `=` instead of `LIKE`.  The ids look like numbers, so you should use number operations.  `LIKE` is a string operation.
- `ORDER` is a bad name for a table because it is a SQL keyword.
- As a general rule, in a `LEFT JOIN`, you don't want the aggregation keys to be from the *second* table, because those values could be `NULL`.